# Getting detached entity passed to persist with @ManyToMany bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am having difficulty persisting entity with many-to-many relationship (bidirectional) with JPA. Below are the sample code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aentity")
public class AEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",
            unique = true)
    @TableGenerator(initialValue = 1,
            name = "aentity_id_generator",
            pkColumnName = "table_name",
            pkColumnValue = "aentity",
            table = "id_generator",
            valueColumnName = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "aentity_id_generator",
            strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private BigInteger id;

    @JoinTable(name = "bentity_aentities")
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<BEntity> bentities;

    /* getters and setters follows */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "bentity")
public class BEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",
            unique = true)
    @TableGenerator(initialValue = 1,
            name = "bentity_id_generator",
            pkColumnName = "table_name",
            pkColumnValue = "bentity",
            table = "id_generator",
            valueColumnName = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "bentity_id_generator",
            strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private BigInteger id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bentities")
    private Set<AEntity> aentities;

    /* getters and setters follows */
}
```

Below is the dto to entity converter...

```
public class DtoToEntityConverter {
   public void convertToEntity(AEntityDto aDto, AEntity a) {
      a.setBEntities(aDto.getBEntities().parallelStream().
         .map(bDto -> {
            return toBEntity(bDto); //this will just copy/transfer the properties from bEntityDto to bEntity.
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
   }
}
```

Scenario 1: Saving AEntity with BEntity (id = null) - OK

Scenario 2: Saving AEntity with existing BEntity (id = id existing in db)

The following exception occurs in Scenario 2: 
Been looking for same questions in stackoverflow and tried different combination and suggestion but with no lock.

```
detached entity passed to persist: BEntity; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: BEntity"
```

Can anybody help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

In the second entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="bentities")
private Set<AEntity> aentities;
```

In the first entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinTable(name="bentity_aentities", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="aentity_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="bentity_id")) 
private Set<BEntity> bentities;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the owning entity should be AEntity, the one without the "mappedBy", so the above code is not appropriate in this case since the weak entity (one with the mappedBy) has no capability to save/update the owning entity (BEntity in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my problem. It was the issue in DTO to Entity converter (my bad).

Previous converter:

```
public AEntity toAEntity(@NotNull AEntityDto aentityDto) {
     AEntity aentity = new AEntity();
     copyProperties(aentityDto, aentity);
     return aentity;
}
```

Refactored converter: Return the reference of the existing entity.

```
public AEntity toAEntity(@NotNull AEntityDto aentityDto) {
     AEntity aentity = aRepository.findSingleByTitle(aentityDto.getTitle());
     if(aentity == null) {
         aentity = new AEntity();
         copyProperties(aentityDto, aentity);
     }
     return aentity;
}
```

Thanks.